# After set Allow Arbitrary Loads,my http request still got the error message Transport Security has blocked a cleartext

Tags: xcode, app-transport-security, mknetworkkit

I set the Allow Arbitrary Loads option to YES, allow all http request .But when i run app,It still got an error message "Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file."
I do really know, it is not recommend...

[image]

```
NSString *path=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"/su"];
NSMutableDictionary *param=[[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
[param setValue:@"facebook" forKey:@"wd"];
MKNetworkEngine *engine=[[MKNetworkEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"suggestion.baidu.com" customHeaderFields:nil];
MKNetworkOperation *op=[engine operationWithPath:path params:param httpMethod:@"get" ssl:NO];
[op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {

} errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
}];
[engine enqueueOperation:op];
```

Comment: Are you sure you set the setting correctly in your app's Info.plist?  The blanket exception still works (although if you know the domains, why wouldn't you just use exception domains.  It protects your users from insecure connections.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.
The second key overwrites the first.
When I deleted the `Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content` option it started working.
Obviously the `Allow Arbitrary` should be left on YES

You're probably using iOS > 10.0 or macOS > 10.12.

> Version-specific ATS behavior: In a current operating system, the
>   presence of a fine-grained transport security key
>   (NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia, NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent,
>   or NSAllowsLocalNetworking) overrides the value of the
>   NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to NO. This allows you to set
>   NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES if needed for your app in older
>   operating systems, without disabling ATS generally in current
>   operating systems.

[https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW68)

Answer (score 0):

After I set the exception domain,It works! But It means the Allow Arbitrary Loads doesn't works?